# Default http connection timeout in maven

Tags: maven, http, timeout

It's possible to define a connection timeout for a single server inside the maven configuration file.

```
 <settings>
   ...
   <mirrors>
     <mirror>
       <id>my-own-nexus</id>
       <name>Other Mirror Repository</name>
       <url>http://nexus.my.own.net.intra</url>
       <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
     </mirror>
   </mirrors>
   <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-server</id>
      <configuration>
        <timeout>120000</timeout>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```

According to the maven doc, the default timeout is 30 minutes. That timeout is used if no timeout for a specific server is configured.

I want to override the default timeout. If maven communicates with a server and there is no timeout configured for that specific server, the configured default timeout should be used.

Comment: First if you use an internal repository manager you should redirect everything via that one which means you have to use `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` furthermore if you repository manager has timeouts than you have network issues which you have to fix first...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately nothing points to the actual question. We use a mirror and it works fine. The request that should run into a timeout quicker is pointing to an URL outside of our intranet and is correctly blocked by our firewall. After a warning as the effect, the build process continues. All I want is the timeout to occur quicker.

Sidenote: During the build process, some transitively linked libraries have pom files, which let maven download libraries directly from outside repositories. That is not allowed in our case. All in all: Mirror is fine. network is fine.

Comment: If you use a repository manager you should handle everything via the repository manager that's the simple thing and that's the reason from suggestion to use `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` if you build has run once successfully everything is cached in the repository manager and you don't need any timeouts etc. ....

Comment: Yeah, it should, but it doesn't :( In our case, there is a transitive dependency to a library, whichs pom file contains the address to the repository "repository.jboss.org/nexus.../". And it seems, that maven uses this address to download a specific library, no matter what repositories we define in the maven settings. That's were the timeout occurs, because of our firewall conditions. Therefore, until we have figured out what exactly happens there, we want the timeout to occur quicker.